# "error: passing 'const XXX' as 'this'" with function of the std

Tags: c++, c++20

I have this error described in the title with one of my functions. From what I've read, a "`passing XXX as 'this'`" error occurs when we try to pass a constant variable in a non-constant parameter. The thing is that the function causing it is from the std, and my compiler (`g++ Ubuntu 11.0.0-19ubuntu1`, with `-std=c++20`) seems to fail to choose the right override.
The errors occurs when calling this function :

```
double Matrix::sum(const CityList cities) const{
  double res=0;
  for(size_t i=0; i<cities.size()-1; i++)
     res+=values[citiesIndex[cities[i]]][citiesIndex[cities[i+1]]];
  return res+values[citiesIndex[cities.back()]][citiesIndex[cities.front()]];
}
```

It basically returns the total weight of the path taken by reaching the cities present in `CityList aka std::vector<std::string> cities`, in order and back (I'm working on graphs). For example `matrix.sum({"London","Paris","Madrid"};` will return the distance from London to Paris, plus from Paris to Madrid, plus from Madrid to London. 
`Matrix` is a class with members:
`std::vector<std::vector<double>> values` the cells of the Matrix containing the weight of each egde of the graph
`std::map<std::string,size_t> citiesIndex` is used to find the right rows and columns from a `std::string` (the name of the city).
When compiling, I get an error message like :
`passing 'const std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, long unsigned int>' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers`,
and as a note it shows:

```
in call to ...
492|      operator[](const key_type& __k)
```

I think it's the [] operator of `std::map` that should be called as `operator[](const key_type& __k) const` instead, but how can I force the compiler to use this one ? I'm sure it's a synthax problem and I'm not using things like they are intended to.
This error message is shown four times, pointing :

```
...citiesIndex[...]...
                  ^
```

At the moment, the fix I made was to make the instance of Matrix non-constant (declaring `double Matrix::sum(const CityList cities);` ), but I really don't like this solution, and I would like to know how I could make the instance constant without errors, and what I've done wrong. Thanks.
**EDIT**
Just use `citiesIndex.at(...)` instead of `citiesIndex[...]`

Comment: `std::map::operator[]` is not a `const` function, so you can't call it on a `const` object

Comment: You might want [`std::map::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) or [`std::map::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find).

Comment: `std::map::operator[]` is a little quirky / suprising, as it is not just doing element lookup, instead it does element lookup and potential insertion. Actually it is rather handy, but different from other containers `[]`

Comment: `std::map::operator[] is not a const function` so this is not a question of override, it just does not exist ? I will try with `at()`.